# A document sharing and collaboration framework and integrate into drupal

Tags: drupal-7, document, google-docs

I am looking for a way to create a document sharing website and integrate that into drupal. Are there any frameworks which can help me create a document sharing site? To put it simply, i am looking to create something like google docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PiratePad](http://drupal.org/project/piratepad). Though it's only for Drupal 6 right now, you may want to help out and port it to Drupal 7. You will find the source code on [Github](http://github.com/markwk/piratepad). You can try it out at [piratepad.net](http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/newpad).

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [FileDepot](https://drupal.org/project/filedepot). It is a Document Management module and it is available for D6 and D7.